# Functional dependencies A->B and C->B, but not AC->B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relation-algebra

If I have a relation:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 2 8
```

Where $A\mapsto B$ and $C \mapsto B$. Doesn't that mean that $AC \mapsto B$? How can you even have this relation? What is the primary key?

I'm looking at this slide 10 on this power point: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/cs5530/slides/lecture13.pdf

I would think that if $A$ and $C$ are the same, then $B$ must also be the same. If you can prove this, please show how. The substitute teacher for the day (prof's PhD student) says it can't be done.

EDIT:
Wouldn't you just show it by saying:

$AC \mapsto BC$ by augmentation
Then, since $C \mapsto B$... you could write $AC \mapsto $B?

Comment: What does `AC` mean? Element-wise multiplication? Edit: ops. I've just noticed `(relation-algebra)` tag. Notation might be known there..

Comment: Sorry, AC being A AND B.

Comment: Are you asking if A and C can be considered a compound primary key in the given relational table?

Comment: @hardmath: Well, yes. It's just that I'm more focused on whether you can prove that AC->B given A->B and C->B. However, if someone can prove to me that it can be a compound primary key of this table, then it'll answer the same question right?

Comment: It's obvious that if B depends functionally on A, and B depends functionally on C, that B depends functionally on the combined values of A and C.  The way you phrased things in terms of "if A and C are the same, then B must also be the same" was a little confusing, and perhaps that's why the substitute teacher responded as he/she did.

Comment: Ah, just proved it to him. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "slide 10" of the presentation you linked to above illustrates "Lossy Decomposition".  That is, if a single table as above (3 rows, 3 columns A/B/C) is such that A and C are each primary keys for the table, then separating the table into two, one having the dependence of B on A, the other having the dependence of B on C, and joining them back together on values of B will produce additional combinations of fields (extra rows) just when the column B contains duplicate values.

But your question seems to be on a different point.  If the value of A uniquely determines a row of the table, and a value of C also uniquely determines a row of the table, then a combination of both A and C also uniquely determines a row.  I'd double check, but I think this could be restated in terms of how "normalized" the table is.

Answer (score 1):

Just proved it to him:

By augmentation: AC->BC
By decomposition: AC->B and AC->C

Sorry for such a simple question. I should have figured it out earlier. Blah.

Comment: Note that your proof only requires A -> B in order to prove AC -> B.  In effect either A *or* C being enough information to determine B will imply the combination of A *and* C determines B.